# grunt-contrib-imagemin skipping files and folders

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm trying to use grunt-contrib-imagemin to recursively process a directory of images. Config looks like this:

```
    imagemin: {
        mytarget: {
            options: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '../../uploads',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest: '.tmp/uploads'
            }]
        }
    }
```

In this form it only processes one sub-directory of the 'uploads' folder. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, can anyone spot my dumb mistake?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',` instead of `src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',`?

Please see [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) for more details.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see your answer when you posted - I get the same thing using that format, unfortunately